# Neo4j Bolt driver, javascript, handling integers

Tags: javascript, neo4j

In Javascript, the Neo4j Bolt driver returns {low:lll, high:hhh} objects in place of integers.  Awesome for 64-bit integers, but it raises a few issues in my humble Javascript web apps.  It now appears I need to go through all of my front-side scripts and check for type 'object' wherever I may receive a date or number from the server, and then either use the Bolt driver's conversion routines (having loaded the driver over to the client), or build my own.  After putting it off for too long, I've just upgraded from neo4j 2.3 to 3.2 and I'm waist-deep in converting to Bolt, but the full implications of that little addendum in the Bolt docs about integers is starting to sink in.

So Neo4j People: is this Bolt driver worth the trouble?  Is the odd-ball approach to delivering integers stable or will it be fixed at some point--e.g., by a directive to the driver telling how numbers should be rendered?  Is there a trick to dealing with this I don't know about?  Should I back out and return to Akeem's node-neo4j driver?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Addendum: The issue turns up in the neo4j-javascript-driver issues list (153, 122, 106, etc.).  The methods of the Bolt driver (InSafeRange, int, etc.) are presented as a resolution.  However this implies hard-coding conversions against a fixed set of data entities.  Normally, the driver should take a directive and only convert 64-bit numbers to {high: low:} objects as a last resort.  Converting all integers to objects and then requiring a server to hard-code re-conversion of most into JS numbers is a huge waste of time.  Question is, will they fix it?  When?

Comment: I think it would be far more confusing to have the driver only convert some numbers to use the Integer object (e.g. {high: low:}). The user of the driver would then need to check every value to see if it had been converted or not, which is a lot of effort. Better to be consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now possible to return native integers in javascript instead of neo4j integer objects as configuration `disableLosslessIntegers: true` on the driver. However, this should only be used if you are sure the number is within the safe integer range in javascript.

```js
var driver = neo4j.driver(
  'neo4j://localhost',
  neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'password'),
  { disableLosslessIntegers: true }
)
```

See [enabling native numbers](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#enabling-native-numbers) on the neo4j-javascript-driver repo for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Neo4j is clearly moving toward using the BOLT protocol, and associated drivers, for all interaction with the database. The protocol itself returns up to 64 bit integers (https://boltprotocol.org/v1/#ints).

However, Javascript has only a Number type, which is floating point, and will only represent integers accurately to 53 bits (http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5).

To enable Javascript code to accurately handle integers larger than 53 bits requires encoding those numbers into a different type. The Neo4j Javascript driver has introduced the Integer object for that purpose (https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/class/src/v1/integer.js~Integer.html). Fortunately, that object contains numerous utility methods, including [`toInt()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/class/src/v1/integer.js~Integer.html#instance-method-toInt) and [`toNumber()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/class/src/v1/integer.js~Integer.html#instance-method-toNumber) for converting back to regular Javascript types (with loss-of-precision, should the Integer be larger than 2^53, which can be checked using [`inSafeRange()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/variable/index.html#static-variable-inSafeRange)).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm sticking with Bolt, but this approach: a) breaks data separation, as it requires hard-coded utility methods on a per-property basis; b) wastes time, as my front-line server is now converting all ints to objects, then testing and converting them all back; c) contaminates client-side code, as many of these objects are passed to the client (so client must also load the driver or provide alternative conversion methods).  In a JS driver, I'd prefer an optional directive when I run the query, allowing me to tell the driver to truncate to JS numbers and not convert to objects.

Comment: I'll leave it to the Neo4j team to answer on their github issue if they'd like to introduce such a "optional directive". Personally, I don't follow your reasoning. Neo4j server already returns the integer, via Bolt, as a 64bit int (https://boltprotocol.org/v1/#ints). The javascript driver represents that as two 32bit ints to work around the 53bit limitation in Javascript. If your code can safely assume no ints exceed 53bits, you can convert to a regular Javascript Number. The overhead of all of this should be very, very minimal (Javascript not being all that efficient anyway!).

Answer (score 1):

In answer to my questions:

a) Bolt driver is tightly-coupled to neo4j using sockets and custom protocol (thanks Chris for the pointer); therefore I think it's worth tackling; however, there are some issues, since you do in fact have to add conversion routines at every point an integer is returned from the db in all server and client scripts; also, if you don't use 64-bit integers, as I do not, then the driver is converting all ints into objects and then you must convert them all back again, so it's a bit of extra weight on the server.

b) I raised an issue with neo4j-driver devs, requesting an option on the 'run' method that would cause the driver to return Javascript numbers up to 2^53 or raise an exception on out-of-bounds integers; this would make the upgrade easier and let the server run cleaner in cases like mine; this request is pending;

c) As for shortcuts, I used the following; hope they help someone:

1)  First, to avoid having to load the neoj4-driver/library to the client, I copied the driver's conversion routine.  I add the following 2 lines to my client-side scripts; then I can call *bolt_num( n )* to convert to numbers:

```
const TWO_PWR_32_DBL = (1 << 16) * (1 << 16);
const bolt_num = function(n){ return typeof n == 'object'? n.hasOwnProperty('low')?  n.high * TWO_PWR_32_DBL + (n.low >>> 0) : n : n; }
```

2)  After changing 50 or so errors, I looked into patching the driver to return js numbers.  The temporary fix below doesn't catch out-of-bounds ints, but as I said, I don't need this.  Changes apply to the neo4j-javascript-driver (v1.4) in one file: *node_modules/neo4j-driver/internal/packstream.js*, starting around line 400 or so.  My 5 replacement lines are commented as *// new*; lines they replace are commented out.  In my application code, the changes I had already made continue to work--the neo4j-driver conversions accept plain integers.  So this allows me to get up and running much faster, adding the numeric conversions at my own pace--unless I decide to just stay with the modified driver so as not to slow down my node server.

```
key: "unpack",
value: function unpack(buffer) {
  var marker = buffer.readUInt8();
  if (marker == NULL) {
    return null;
  } else if (marker == TRUE) {
    return true;
  } else if (marker == FALSE) {
    return false;
  } else if (marker == FLOAT_64) {
    return buffer.readFloat64();
  } else if (marker >= 0 && marker < 128) {
    return marker;  // new
    //return (0, _integer.int)(marker);
  } else if (marker >= 240 && marker < 256) {
    return marker-256; // new
    //return (0, _integer.int)(marker - 256);
  } else if (marker == INT_8) {
    return buffer.readInt8(); // new
    //return (0, _integer.int)(buffer.readInt8());
  } else if (marker == INT_16) {
    return buffer.readInt16(); // new
    //return (0, _integer.int)(buffer.readInt16());
  } else if (marker == INT_32) {
    return buffer.readInt32(); // new
    //var b = buffer.readInt32();
    //return (0, _integer.int)(b);
  } else if (marker == INT_64) {
    var high = buffer.readInt32();
    var low = buffer.readInt32();
    var TWO_PWR_32_DBL = (1 << 16) * (1 << 16);  // new
    return high * TWO_PWR_32_DBL + (low >>> 0);  // new
    //return new _integer2.default(low, high);
  } else if (marker == STRING_8) {
```